# Getting AWS S3 Client to work in multi-threaded code

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload to S3 within my asynchronous Java code

private void submitCallablesWithExecutor()
                throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {

```
        ExecutorService executorService = null;

        try {
            executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

            Future<String> task1Future = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {

                public String call() {
                    try {
                        processExportRequest(xmlPutRequest_, customizedRequest_, response_);
                        return "Success";
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        return ex.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            });

        } finally {
            executorService.shutdown();

            try {
                if (!executorService.awaitTermination(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    executorService.shutdownNow();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                executorService.shutdownNow();
            }
        }
    }
```

within processExportRequest I am calling upload to S3.  I have tried both S3Client and S3AsyncClient.  In both cases, I am getting following error:

Failed to upload to S3: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Interrupted waiting to refresh the value.

I don't see anywhere in my code that's calling Thread.interrupt(), and everything else seems to work fine, just not S3 upload.  Maybe the multithreaded nature of Java Future is not compatible with AWS SDK?  Thanks.

Comment: You could just use the S3 Async Client, it returns a future. Else you may want to debug/look at the code in your finally block. You're immediately shutting down your executor after submitting to it.

Comment: Actually I am not sure that's true.  ExecutorService.shutdown javadoc says:

Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I changed Future to CompletableFuture, and combine two of them (in sequence):

```
private CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> processExportAndUploadAsync()
            throws IOException {
        CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> result = processExportAsync()
                .thenCompose(fileName -> uploadS3Async(fileName));

        return result;
    }
```

It seems to work.